# Converse of Cantor's intersection theorem in a complete metric space?

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, metric-spaces

Let $(X,d)$ be a complete metric space. If intersection of a decreasing sequence $(C_{n})$ of closed sets is singleton then can we say and prove that $diam(C_{n})$ approaches $0$ as $n$ approaches $\infty$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No. Consider $X=\Bbb R$ with the standard distance and the sequence $C_n=\{0\}\cup[n,+\infty)$.

**Added:**
For a uniformly bounded counterexample, consider $X=\ell^\infty$ and the sequence $$C_n=\{x\in\ell^\infty\,:\, (\forall k\le n,\ x_k=0)\wedge(\forall k>n,\ \lvert x_k\rvert\le 1)\}$$

Their intersection is again $\{0\}$, but $\operatorname{diam}C_n= 2$

**Added:** Another easy uniformly bounded counterexample is the same I have provided in the beginning, just with the distance $\min\{1,\lvert x-y\rvert\}$ on $\Bbb R$. As elementary as it might be, it proves that the claim does not hold in general  even if the hypothesis is "uniformly bounded $C_n$s in a complete, locally compact metric space".

Comment: there intersection is {0}?

Comment: Their intersection is $\{0\}$.

Comment: Thanks. I was trying to prove a result using converse of  cantor intersection theoem

Comment: is the norm on $\ell^\infty$ also called infinity norm

Comment: I'd say yes. I'm referring to $\lVert x\rVert_\infty=\sup\{\lvert x_n\rvert\,:\,n\in\Bbb N\}$.